# Too many redirects with https only on one rewrite rule

Tags: ssl, https

I am not able to understand why this rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ file.php?lang=xxx&id=$3 [L]
```

causes too many redirects since I have installed the SSL certificate.
All the other rules for different sections are working perfectly.

Comment: Hi..We encourage you to get involved in the community, but please don’t thank in the question. It eventually degrades the quality of the site. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, the mistake was not the rewrite rule but a wrong script.